# Замена подстроки на количество её вхождений

Tags: python, строки

Есть ли в питоне какая-то встроенная функция, которая заменит все подстроки на количество их вхождений в строку, например:
исходная - 123345
выход - 112211
Если нет, то подскажите, как это лучше реализовать

Comment: `''.join([str(s.count(i)) for i in s])`, где s - строка

Comment: Все подстроки или все символы? Определитесь поточнее с определением `подстрока`